# Detect scroll on bottom on iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect if i'm at the bottom of a page. This works fine on any browser - but not on iPhone.

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())){
alert('on bottom'); 
}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()){
       alert('on bottom'); 
   }
});
```